# Creating a descriptor file and netcdf file in GrADS

Tags: grads

is there a program that creates a .ctl and netCDF file readable in GrADS? Am stack in trying creating one through coding in Fortran. someone assist kindly

Answer (score 1):

What type of file are you using? (binary like TRMM PR?).

[1] Know your data. This is the first step.

[2] Read this link carefully. http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/gadoc/descriptorfile.html
You will learn about the contents of the ctl file from this link.

[3] After you created a ctl file you can use cdo.

```
cdo -f nc import_binary infile.ctl outfile.nc
```

See this link: https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-5150002.9.1

[4] Or you can use sdfwrite to create a netcdf file from GRADS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create netCDF and .ctl files from existed binary data file (.bin file)?

In this case, wgrib2 and the netCDF Operators (NCO) can help you to do that.

Convert .bin file to .nc (netCDF) by `wgrib2` and then dump data which you want from .nc to .ctl by `ncdump`.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).